# Weird namespace addition when importing a typelib

Tags: windows, visual-studio, com, com-interop, midl

I want to add a method accepting `IStream*` to my COM interface. Here's the idl excerpt:

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";
import "objidl.idl";//IStream is declared in this .idl file
[
    uuid(uuidhere),
    version(1.0)
]
library MyLibrary
{
    importlib("stdole32.tlb");
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    [
     object,
     uuid("interfaceid"),
     dual,
     nonextensible,
     oleautomation,
    hidden
    ]
    interface IMyInterface : IUnknown {
        HRESULT LoadStream( [in] IStream* stream );
        HRESULT LoadUnknown( [in] IUnknown* unkn );
    };
}
```

I compile the `.idl` file and import the typelib in another project.

When I review the `.tlb` in OLEView  file I see that the `IStream` is declared inside my typelib but `IUnknown` is not. This causes problems - when I try to call `IMyInterface::LoadStream()` in another project C++ says it can't convert `IStream*` to `MyLibrary::IStream*`. In the same time it doesn't complain about IUnknown.

Why does MIDL put IStream definition inside the typelib and not treat it as a global definition?

Comment: FYI, ocidl.idl imports oaidl.idl, oaidl.dil imports objidl.idl, and objidl.idl imports unknwn.idl.  So you just need to import ocidl.idl.

Answer (score 0):

You have two IStreams, one global (declared in objidl.idl), another in the MyLibrary namespace (declared in your idl). Remove the one in the MyLibrary namespace.

If you plan to support script clients, I suggest you also expose an IDispatch interface as IStream isn't supported by script languages.

Comment: That's what I don't get. What exactly do I do to remove the in-typelib declaration?

Comment: remove the IStream declaration from idl.

Comment: If I remove import "objidl.idl" the behaviour remains the same. What else can I do?

Comment: remove the IStream declaration interface IMyInterface : IUnknown {
        HRESULT LoadStream( [in] IStream* stream );
        HRESULT LoadUnknown( [in] IUnknown* unkn );
    };

Comment: I don't declare IStream, I only use it to specify the method parameter.